# Golang Newton Method Implementation - Major Confusion

Tags: go, newtons-method

### CONTEXT

Among many intuitive solutions online, I've trying hard to understand this one implementation which was posted on **r/golang**.

Just to enrich the context, here's the problem statement in the [golang tutorial](https://go.dev/tour/flowcontrol/8):

> As a way to play with functions and loops, let's implement a square root function: given a number x, we want to find the number z for which z² is most nearly x.

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/ua2v9u/day_1100_of_learning_golang/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)'s the link to the post and here's the code from that post which I've slightly changed to understand it better:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Sqrt(x, z float64) float64 {

    z -= ((z*z - x) / (2*z))
    
    for z*z > x {
        z -= ((z*z - x) / (2*z))
    }
    return z
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(100, 1))
}
```

### DOUBT

**How is it that for any given value of z and x, z^2 always ends up a greater value than x in the first iteration** (that is before the beginning of the for loop)?

I have this doubt since I wonder if there's a way whereby both z^2 is less than x and the returned z is an incorrect root to x.

I'm mostly convinced that z^2 cannot be less than x in the first iteration since I couldn't find any combination of z and x proving otherwise, in so far as I could try. I would greatly appreciate an explanation as to why z^2 is always greater than x on the first iteration, if indeed that is true.

Answer (score 0):

this is because
z -= ((z * z - x) / (2*z)) is equal to

z = z - ((z * z - x) / (2*z))

because in first place value of z is always way less than x  **so z * z - x will be negative**

and we have z - (negative value ) so this will be positive for example a-(-b) = a+b

but as z starts to grow the value z*z - x  will become less and less

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to understand your answer better. What is the Newton Method Expression doing to z that makes z^2 always greater than x? For e.g., given x = 2 and can z be anything that would make z something like 0.40 after the first Newton Method implementation? If no, why not?

Comment: z ^ 2 somewhere must be less than x beucase in other way we will have infinit loop in     for z*z > x

Comment: we will have this operation when z ^ 2 is less than x and when it will be happen ? just write mathematical expression after first iterations the value of z will be less and less until z ^ 2 > x will be false then we will return z